# Slope of plane and vector

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $(a,b,c)$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ on a plane whose projection on the (a,c)-space has negative slope m. Let $n$ be a normal to this plane. Let $c>0$.

Assume that $n\cdot (a,b,c)\le 0$.

> > Now consider $(a,c)$. Then, under the assumption that $n\cdot (a,b,c)\le 0$, we have that
> >     $$
> > 0>\frac{c}{a}>m.
> > $$

To be honest I do not see that.

And to the interpretation: Does this mean there is a "line" between a and c that decreases less than the projection of the plane on (a,c)-space?

Comment: You write "a vector on a plane" but $(a,b,c)$ does not belong to that plane. And then, what is (a,c)-space?

Comment: Why is it no vector an that plane? It is a vector with some direction and it starts from the plane. - With (a,c)-plane I mean two dimension, i.e. the y-coordinate is 0.

Comment: Sorry but "it starts from the plane" means nothing to me. Would it make any difference if it started elsewhere? As for the (a,c)-space it would be better to call it (x,z)-plane. But in what sense a plane has a projection on the (x,y)-plane? That plane must then be perpendicular to the (x,y)-plane?

Comment: Maybe I did not describe it well, sorry. I mean take a point on that plane. From that point, the vector starts.  -- The plane is such that when projecting it on the (x,z)- space, you get a line.

Answer (score 0):

The given plane is perpendicular to the $(x,z)$-plane, because its projection onto the $(x,z)$-plane is a line of slope $m$. But then the equation of that plane is $z=mx+k$ and a vector normal to it is $n=(-m,0,1)$.

From $n\cdot(a,b,c)\le0$ it follows then $-ma+c\le0$, that is: $c\le ma$. But we know that $m<0$ and $c>0$, so it must be $a<0$. Dividing both sides by $a$ gives then: $c/a\ge m$, which can be combined with $c/a<0$ to obtain the final result $0>c/a\ge m$.

I don't think it is possible to exclude the case $c/a=m$ (to get a strict inequality) without some further assumption. Notice that $c/a=m$ means that vector $(a,b,c)$ is parallel to the plane: if that is excluded by some unmentioned assumption, then strict inequality holds.

Comment: When I see it right, your normal vector $n$ starts from the origin. What I meant was a normal vector starting on the plane. However, the first component $n_1$ and the third component $n_3$ of it should be positive, and hence $n_1\cdot a+n_3\cdot c\le 0\Leftrightarrow c/a\leq -n_1/n_3 <0$. But I do not see that $c/a > m$ or at least $c/a\geq m$.

Comment: As I told you in a comment above, a vector doesn't "start" anywhere. If you like to think of a vector $\vec v$ as applied to some point $P$, then you could say that it "starts" at $P$ and "ends" at $Q=P+\vec v$, but that doesn't change the coordinates of the vector. Any vector $\vec n$ perpendicular to the given plane can be written as $\vec n=k(-m,0,1)$, where $k$ is an arbitrary constant. You can apply it to a point on the plane, if you like, but that changes nothing of what I wrote above.